# Can't login to Super User

Tags: support, openid, login

I have tried using my openID and some of the other options and it always says it's an invalid ID...any idea what may be happening?

Comment: It's not Google is it?

Comment: nope it´s not, I don't know what is it

Comment: What's the OpenID and what's your password?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not find an answer in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openid+faq) (especially the [troubleshooting tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)) email the team!

Answer (score 0):

This was very likely due to a period when the OpenID provider let their security certificate expire. (You are/were using openid.org, I'll bet, Proxify — this has happened more than once, with them.)

When that happens, the Stack Exchange network servers fail to make the HTTPS connection to openid.org, and the signon attempt fails somewhat cryptically. (It'd actually be kind of nice if the site(s) here recognized that it was an HTTPS certificate rejection that was blocking the openid authentication attempt, and returned a more-explanatory message to the user.)

We just went through another period like that, with openid.org, which has *fortunately* now ended. As of 2012-03-11 openid.org once again has a valid security certificate.

Of course, because their new certificate expires in just 1 year, come 2013-03-13 we'll be in the same mess all over again... unless someone is more on the ball next time, that is.

Personally, now that I finally have access to my stackexchange account again, the **very first thing** I did was go to "my logins" and add a secondary signon method. Openid.org obviously can't be trusted as a sole provider, which is a shame. (Though it was definitely my fault for making them a single point of failure for my login, in the first place.)

Comment: This is also a two and a half year old question..

Comment: Yes it is. But one for which no actual answers (or even possible explanations) were provided, which would have left anyone with the same issue who finds it kind of un-helped.

Which would be OK, if it were unlikely that anyone WOULD be arriving here with the same issue. Unfortunately, as I explained, this problem is going to come up for openid.org users every time they drop the ball and let their security certificate expire. That's already happened several times in the past, and there's unfortunately no reason to think it might not happen again. The latest certificate expires on 2013-03-13...